# R data long-wide restructure

Tags: r, data-structures, aggregate, dcast

I am currently working with data in R. My dataset looks like this (except with about 3 million observations):

This is the current structure of the data:

[image: Current structure of data]

And I have two objectives...

Objective 1 is to structure it so that it looks like this:

[image: objective 1]

then my second objective is to go back to the original structure and make it look like this:

[image: objective 2]

I have tried variations of aggregate with dcast (which is apparently being deprecated...?)

so, for example, I have tried this:

```
df2 <- dcast(df1, Store + Sales~ Year, value.var = "Sales")
```

or even

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Store, Year) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('Sales'), sum))
```

And I get a diagonal of sales totals across years, but then I'm unable to summarize them so that it looks like

```
Store Year1 Year2
A       $$   $$
B       $$   $$
```

Since there is so much data, it looks like a bunch of stacked identity matrices ...except, instead of 1's there are sales values for the years (there are many many years, not just two).

I am looking for suggestions on how to proceed. One package I found was 'pivottabler' and I have not used it yet, I wanted to see if anyone had any better suggestions first.

***:::Much appreciated:::***

Comment: Can you provide part of your dataset using `dput` ? Copy output of `dput(head(df, 10))`. We need some data to work with and an image will not help here. See this post on how to make a reproducible example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Comment: With `dcast` formulas I always think `row variables ~ column variables`. Can't test without sample data, but for Obj 1, try `df_obj1 <-  dcast(df1, Store ~ Year, value.var = "Sales", fun.aggregate = sum)`, and for Obj 2, try `df_obj2 <- dcast(df1, Store + Item ~ Year, value.var = "Sales", fun.aggregate = sum)`.

Comment: But yes, the whole `reshape2` package is mostly deprecated, though `data.table::dcast` is better than ever. The tidyverse replacement is `tidyr::pivot_wider`, which is much more flexible and powerful than `reshape2::dcast`. [The Pivoting vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/pivot.html) is a great place to start.

Comment: I'm sorry if this post isn't a reproducible example, but @GregorThomas actually answered my question. I used pivot_wider and in about 5 minutes I had the data structure I spent several hours trying to achieve. Thank you so much. I'm sorry for the inefficient structure of this post. It is my first post. next time I will add the data I'm using and make it reproducible.